# how to fix Cannot convert return expression of type 'UIView' to return type 'ARView' issue in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, arkit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PygOo.png)

```
class MyCustomUIViewController: UIViewController {
    let coachingOverly = ARCoachingOverlayView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let session = arView.session
        // this is a view that display standardized onbording instructions to direct users towards specific goal.
        let coachingOverly = ARCoachingOverlayView()
        // this is an intger bit mask that determines how the reciever resized itself.
        coachingOverly.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        coachingOverly.goal = .anyPlane
        coachingOverly.session = session
        arView.addSubview(coachingOverly)
        // Load the "Opject" scene from the "dumu" Reality File
        let anchor = try! Dumu.loadScene()
        
        // Add the Opject anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        self.view.addSubview(arView)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        coachingOverly.setActive(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code not as a screenshot. It is hard to answer it by retyping

Answer (score 1):

From your picture in the ARViewContainer I see....

In

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView // ..... -> you specify a return type of ARView
```

But next you instantiate a new UIView for the return

```
... = MyCustomViewController() // Seems to be an UIView->
```

which seems to be an UIView and you return it. But you have to return an ARView which is a subclass of UIView. Maybe you can downcast the MyCustomViewController with

```
let viewController = MyCustomUIViewController() as ARView
```

or you may change the class of MyCustomUIViewController() to ARView in its definition. For a more detailed explanation I need at least the definition of MyCustomUIViewController()